# Pandas DataFrame - splitting a column into 2 columns, based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, multi-index

struggling with this one using a pandas dataframe, I have data as follows:

```
Animal     Nationality   Type     Value
Leopard    India         Age      4.0
Elephant   India         Age      12.0
Leopard    India         Speed    30.0
Elephant   India         Speed    3.0
Leopard    China         Age      5.0
Leopard    China         Speed    27.0
```

I want to effectively merge the data into a dataframe as follows:

```
Animal     Nationality    Age      Speed
Leopard    India          4.0      30.0
Elephant   India          12.0     3.0 
Leopard    China          5.0      27.0
```

I have looked up semi-similar problems, but have had no joy, I think due to the nature of changing the size of the dataframe, any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use [DataFrame.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) or [DataFrame.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html):

```
new_df=df.pivot_table(index=['Animal','Nationality'],columns='Type',values='Value')
print(new_df)


Type                   Age  Speed
Animal   Nationality             
Elephant India        12.0    3.0
Leopard  China         5.0   27.0
         India         4.0   30.0
```

---

```
new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(new_df)


Type    Animal Nationality   Age  Speed
0     Elephant       India  12.0    3.0
1      Leopard       China   5.0   27.0
2      Leopard       India   4.0   30.0
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response, I also realised I need to include multi-indexing, which is an issue, and have updated the question, would you be able to look at this and update your response? Much appreciated.

Comment: I  update the solution. Please accept it  if it is correct

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't resolved it for me. I have tried this using pivot_table and got the error: "No numeric types to aggregate" - I guess because my values are strings.
I also tried using pivot in python and got "Length of values passed is 6, index implies 2"

Comment: `new_df=df.pivot_table(index=['Animal','Nationality'],columns='Type',values='Value', aggfunc=''.join)`